# using 'or' in python always evaluate to true and it can clash with other conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple Boolean expression in Python that should follow this set of rules:

- The parameter "you" is the stylishness of your clothes, in the range
  0..10, and "date" is the stylishness of your date's clothes in the same range.
- The result getting the table is encoded as an `int` value with
  `0=no`, `1=maybe`, `2=yes`.
- If either of you is very stylish, 8 or more, then the result is `2 (yes)`. With the exception that if either of you has style of `2` or
  less, then the result is `0 (no)`. Otherwise the result is `1 (maybe)`.

My code works fine except for a certain condition. What if you have a styling of 8 and your date has a styling or 2 or less? Which result should run and why? Here is my code

```
def date_fashion(you, date):
    if you>=8 or date>=8:
        return 2
    elif you<=2 or date<=2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

if I run date_fashion(10, 2) it should give 0, but it also could give 2.

Which one is the right answer? here both conditions clash at the same time which one is correct? Result 0 or result 2 and why? My code gives 2 but it could also give 0.

Comment: It cannot return 0, because the first condition is true, so it returns 2.

Comment: Your code cannot give 0, in your example because you first check if any has above 8 and if that true you dont check if any are less than 2. You need to clearly define your logic and problem statments before you code. What should be the expected result for the example you gave. Should it be 0 or 2. if it can be either then by what rules do you decide which to return? is it random? or is there some logic that decides

Comment: The conditions are evaluated in the order you wrote them, it is not possible to return `0` in the case you mention

Comment: So it is all about order correct? Like if I switch the order between the first and the second it will give 0 instead of 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The code gives you the result `2` because the condition `you>=8 or date>=8` has priority over the others.
2. The code goes through one condition at a time. And executes the code
   of the first `condition` that returns `Truthy` value.

> Check out [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) article about `Truthy and Falsy` values.

Answer (score 2):

For your condition: If either of you is very stylish, 8 or more, then the result is 2 (yes). **With the exception that** if either of you has style of 2 or less, then the result is 0 (no), you should put the exception before the normal condition. So then when you see a <2 you return 0.

```
def date_fashion(you, date):
    if you<=2 or date<=2:
        return 0
    elif you>=8 or date>=8:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `date_fashion(10, 2)` it will always return `2` and never `0`. Because `you=10` satisfies condition `you>=8`, then the function executes the `return 0` statement and immediately stops. In that case the next statements will not be run.

Answer (score 1):

try to make priority in defining conditions, from certain  to less certain conditions.

eg.

1.no reservation  when either you or date is <=2 (definitive)

2. yes reservation when either you or date is >=8 (have 1 more condition, none of them should be <=2).
3. maybe reservation in other case

so by defining the less dependent first and than move on to next lvl (here point 2, where it only cancel when point 1 is true) so on and then a last making a general solution here `maybe` , then you can solve.

```
def date_fashion(you, date):
    if you<=2 or date<=2:
        return 0
    elif you>=8 or date>=8:
        return 2
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def date_fashion(you, date):

  condition1=(you>2 and date>2) and (you>=8 or date>=8)
  condition2=(you<=2 or date<=2)
  
  if condition1:
    return 2
  elif condition2:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1
```